# GPS tracker updating location whenever changed using flutter and dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, gps

Create a GPS tracker where the longitude and latitude get updated every time the location changes along with the address and time showing it in an infinite list view.

I could get the Longitude and Latitude but I couldn't get how to update it everytime it changes and also I couldn't add the address and time in a listview so please help me out. Below is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool servicestatus = false;
  bool haspermission = false;
  late LocationPermission permission;
  late Position position;
  String long = "", lat = "";
  late StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream;


  @override
  void initState() {
    checkGps();
    super.initState();
  }

  checkGps() async {
    servicestatus = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (servicestatus) {
      permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
          print('Location permissions are denied');
        } else if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
          print("'Location permissions are permanently denied");
        } else {
          haspermission = true;
        }
      } else {
        haspermission = true;
      }

      if (haspermission) {
        setState(() {
          
        });

        getLocation();
      }
    } else {
      print("GPS Service is not enabled, turn on GPS location");
    }

    setState(() {
      
    });
  }

  getLocation() async {
    position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position.longitude);
    print(position.latitude);

    long = position.longitude.toString();
    lat = position.latitude.toString();


    setState(() {});

    LocationSettings locationSettings = const LocationSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      distanceFilter: 100,
    );

    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream =
        Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
            .listen((Position position) {
      print(position.longitude);
      print(position.latitude);

      long = position.longitude.toString();
      lat = position.latitude.toString();

      setState(() {
        
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ListViewGpsTracker'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text(servicestatus ? "GPS is Enabled" : "GPS is disabled."),
              Text(haspermission ? "GPS is Enabled" : "GPS is disabled."),
              Text("Longitude: $long", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
              Text(
                "Latitude: $lat",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              )
            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't you?

Comment: @blackapps because I don't know how to and I am a beginner.